# finding area under the curve of a value

Tags: gaussian-integral

I am not a mathematician and I would love if you could explain some things to me, please.

I have a data, a list of some values. Minimal value is -3.04, max value is 2.75. I plotted the data and I have seen it looks like a Gaussian curve, the mean is around 0.0001 and std is about one.

The problem is I don't know how to calculate what area under the curve some value from - infinity to value point taken.

For an example: let's say, I get new input -3.7. How could I calculate a percentage of an area between -infinity to -3.7 is in my data? I would appreciate a simple explanation. Perhaps you can just direct me what to study. Thank you.

p.s. values are continous

Comment: It is not clear to me, if the minimum value is -3.04 how can you get a new input at -3.7?  In any case, if you want to integrate a Gaussian function you have to resort to the "error function" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @cholo14 Data is changing with every new input